# How to use linphone-sdk with C#

Tags: linphone, linphone-sdk

I download linphone-sdk from the official website (https://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone) It is very normal for me to using in the project. But When I running, I will prompt linphone.dll not found. I did not find this dll in the downloaded linphone-sdk, only liblinphone.dll.Please someone Help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3IF8.png)

I have tried to use different compilation architectures, but neither can I.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use our pre-built NuGET packages? https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk/-/packages

See the wiki entry that explains how to get started: https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Getting%20started/Windows%20UWP/

Comment: yes，I had try to use it. It also same error：Could not find assembly “LinphoneSDK.Windows”，Unable to load  DLL“linphone”:   I run it with x86

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and solved it by copying all *dll from [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-windows10/tree/master) and copying it into the debug folder.